# :Breakpoint not an editor command - Vim Vdebug

Tags: php, debugging, nginx, vim, xdebug

I've just configured xdebug + vdebug + fpm + nginx + vim stack for server side php debugging, but faced *"Not an editor command"* error in Vim, while trying to set breakpoint with **:Breakpoint**.

The courious thing is that Vdebug seems up and **:help Vdebug** displays help info.

Any thoughts?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use recent vim, you need to install vim-whatever-py2 (say: vim-nox-py2).
For now vim is using python 3 and vdebug is using using version 2.